# Python - unable to call system command

Tags: python, subprocess

I have some python code, from which I want to call another program. This program will

- Print some output to `STDOUT`
- Write a file to disk

Using `call` I get the following behavior;

```
from subprocess import call
call(['./tango_x86_64_release', 'VTS1 ct="N" nt="N" ph="7.2" te="303" io="0.02" seq="MKHPYEEFPTGSKSPYNMSRGAHPGAV"'])
34, File not properly written, try writing it up again, 
1
```

This happens regardless if if the arguments are split into a list or not;

```
call(['./tango_x86_64_release', 'VTS1', 'ct="N"', 'nt="N"', 'ph="7.2"', 'te="303"', 'io="0.02"', 'seq="MKHPYEEFPTGSKSPYNMSRGAHPGAV"'])
34, File not properly written, try writing it up again, 
1
```

I can call this same command from the my terminal

```
./tango_x86_64_release VTS1 ct="N" nt="N" ph="7.2" te="303" io="0.02" seq="MKHPYEEFPTGSKSPYNMSRGAHPGAV"
```

Which works and gives an exit status of 0.

It seems like its the writing to disk which is causing issues, if I break the command then I get the appropriate warning message (i.e. remove an argument, it warns me that the argument is missing).

Using `subprocess.Popen()` gives an `OSError`;

```
import subprocess as sub
output = sub.Popen('./tango_x86_64_release VTS1 ct="N" nt="N" ph="7.2" te="303" io="0.02" seq="MKHPYEEFPTGSKSPYNMSRGAHPGAV"', stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to add `shell=True` to the `Popen` call.

Comment: Seems hard to reproduce outside your environment. Trying to create a small, reproducible use case probably will give you the answer (kind of [rubber-duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging))

Comment: @alecxe - you're my hero. Bang on the money (post it as an answer - I can't believe that's all it took!!)

Comment: @Alex no problems. All I did is just found two relevant threads that I've provided below - people there are your heroes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `shlex.split` to split the command for you:

```
import shlex
call(shlex.split('./tango_x86_64_release VTS1 ct="N" nt="N" ph="7.2" te="303" io="0.02" seq="MKHPYEEFPTGSKSPYNMSRGAHPGAV"'))
```

Note that although you might be able to solve your problem by adding `shell=True`, you should avoid it if possible, since it can be a [security risk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) (search for "shell injection").

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `shell=True` to the `Popen` call.

Also see:

- [Why does subprocess.Popen() with shell=True work differently on Linux vs Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253122/why-does-subprocess-popen-with-shell-true-work-differently-on-linux-vs-windows)
- [Popen error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935151/popen-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)
- [Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) (and why `Passing shell=True can be a security hazard`)