# bat file not running when in another folder with Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file

Very simply I have this code

```
 bat_execution = subprocess.Popen("Bats/test.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which returns the error

```
'Bats' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file
```

However if I move the bat file out of the Bats directory and keep it in the same level as the python code like below, it runs fine:

```
bat_execution = subprocess.Popen("test.bat", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am using python and Windows 7.  I do not get why the path is causing this error.

My test.bat is simply:

```
echo "test success"
```

Comment: Try putting a backslash instead of a forward slash: `"Bats\\test.bat"` or `r"Bats\test.bat"` instead of `"Bats/test.bat"`. I think Windows is interpreting the forward slash as the beginning of a command-line option.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, it's not "Windows" but cmd.exe, which defaults to parsing "/" as a command-line switch for options. the OP should also be able to use `'"Bats/test.bat"'`. Also note that `shell=True` isn't necessary since Windows knows to run cmd.exe for a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmd.exe` does some interesting things to unquoted input command line arguments. The details can be found in this acticle: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/

In your case, the shell is breaking up the string at the `/`, treating it as the start of a flag that will be passed to `Bats`. There are a couple of options available:

- Use `\\` to separate path elements: Change `"Bats/test.bat"` to `"Bats\\test.bat"` or `r"Bats\test.bat"`.
- Quote the input string so that `cmd.exe` parses it correctly: Change `"Bats/test.bat"` to `'"Bats/test.bat"'` or `"\"Bats/test.bat\""`.

Thanks to @eryksun for the second option.

Also note that `shell=True` is a) not necessary on Windows, and b) you still need to quote arguments properly even without it (unlike Unix). See [the second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1253161/2988730) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1253122/2988730) for more details if you are interested.